# And the Best New User of 2017 is

Tags: discussion, users, contest, new-users

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I have created this honorary post based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2017 league the winner is:

## [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/bellatrix)

[image: Bellatrix Rank in the league]

Coming in at a very impressive #6 rank for the year with 26,201 reputation gained in less than 9 months is certainly an achievement to be recognized. Please join in congratulating this exceptional user!

---

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria would be:

- 2016: [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba) - #18 - 15,596 reputation
- 2015: [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis) -   #4 - 35,709 reputation
- 2014: [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/royal-canadian-bandit) - #7 - 14,897 reputation
- 2013: [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111) - #10 - 6,998 reputation
- 2012: [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/dlanod) - #4 - 26,834 reputation
- 2011: [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/jeff) - #1 - 21,720 reputation

Comment: Did I miss out because I joined a few days before 2014?

Comment: @Valorum I knew I'd be hearing from you, but that's the way the cookie crumbles. Also why I kept the "evaluation" simple and straight forward.

Comment: She's also worth a mention for being one of the fastest users ever to get a gold tag badge (for HP, almost as fast as Slytherincess back in 2012).

Comment: Well deserved! (for all these users, really)

Comment: @Valorum - timing is everything :)

Comment: I've been keeping track and was hoping to hit 25k before Bellatrix but she blasted past me in the past month or so - well done indeed!

Answer (score 25):

**Congratulations!**

[image]

Your contribution on the site has been brilliant so far.