# And the Best New User of 2018 is

Tags: discussion, users, new-users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I have <s>created this honorary post</s> stolen [Skooba's honorary post idea from last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11636/58193) based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2018 league the winner is:

## [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/jenayah)

[image: Jenayah Rank in the league]

Coming in at an impressive #9 rank for the year with 14,253 reputation gained in ~9 months is certainly an achievement to be recognised. Please join in congratulating this exceptional user!

---

Note that this year was quite tight with [Alex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/100430/alex) coming in at spot #10 with 13,353 reputation gained in ~7 months.

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria are:

- 2017: [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/bellatrix) - #6 - 26,201 reputation
- 2016: [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba) - #18 - 15,596 reputation
- 2015: [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis) -   #4 - 35,709 reputation
- 2014: [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/royal-canadian-bandit) - #7 - 14,897 reputation
- 2013: [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111) - #10 - 6,998 reputation
- 2012: [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/dlanod) - #4 - 26,834 reputation
- 2011: [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/jeff) - #1 - 21,720 reputation

Comment: Didn't realize it at first, but I'm poised to get it for 2019 with the marvelous rank of 50th place! (Though, a lot can happen in 6 months!)

Answer (score 14):

Well done, and we look forward to all your contributions in the new year and all the years to come as well!

Answer (score 3):

## Go Jenayah!

Congratulations for your exceptional work and immense contributions to our Stack Exchange community!