# And the Best New User of 2019 is

Tags: discussion, users, new-users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users, I am [continuing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) honorary post based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2019 league the winner is:

## [Invisible Trihedron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115696/invisible-trihedron)

[image: Invisible Trihedron User league screen shot]

Coming in at a very impressive #19 rank for the year with 8,239 reputation gained in 8 months is certainly an achievement to be recognized. Please join in congratulating this exceptional user!

---

Honorable Mention to [Stormblessed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102999/stormblessed) for being very active and coming in at #12 (+553) with 10,379 reputation gained but starting their career just a bit before the 2019 year, thus being ranked in 2018 (which isn't hard to do with only needing to gain 200 rep).

---

Previous years' winners based on the criteria are:

- 2018: [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/jenayah) - #9 - 14,253 reputation
- 2017: [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/bellatrix) - #6 - 26,201 reputation
- 2016: [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba) - #18 - 15,596 reputation
- 2015: [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis) -   #4 - 35,709 reputation
- 2014: [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/royal-canadian-bandit) - #7 - 14,897 reputation
- 2013: [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111) - #10 - 6,998 reputation
- 2012: [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/dlanod) - #4 - 26,834 reputation
- 2011: [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/jeff) - #1 - 21,720 reputation

Comment: How come I didn't get an honourable mention [in 2014](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is)?

Comment: @Valorum because I only started doing this in 2017?

Comment: @Valorum, Bella did the same thing to me in 2017 

Comment: Thank you for the recognition! I feel that I am in good company.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron You're still new. Give it time.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron thanks for your interesting and challenging story ID questions!