# And the Best New User of 2020 is

Tags: discussion, users, new-users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I am [continuing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) [honorary](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/and-the-best-new-user-of-2019-is) post based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2020 league the winner is:

## [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/)

[image: Clara Diaz Sanchez User league screen shot]

Coming in at #12 with 9,252 reputation in 11 months is an accomplishment to be proud of. Please join me in congratulating this exceptional new user!

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria are:

| year | user | year rank | reputation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | [Invisible Trihedron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115696/) | 19 | 8,239 |
| 2018 | [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/) | 9 | 14,253 |
| 2017 | [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/) | 6 | 26,201 |
| 2016 | [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/) | 18 | 15,596 |
| 2015 | [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/) | 4 | 35,709 |
| 2014 | [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/) | 7 | 14,897 |
| 2013 | [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/) | 10 | 6,998 |
| 2012 | [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/) | 4 | 26,834 |
| 2011 | [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/) | 1 | 21,720 |

Comment: Thank you! This was a complete surprise, but a very nice one. I'll try to live up to the examples of my illustrious predecessors  ;)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Congrats! Seems like the Asimov topic challenge is standing you in good stead for the start of 2021 too :-)

Comment: Yes, the questions have fallen nicely for me so far. It probably won't continue though.