# And the Best New User of 2021 is

Tags: discussion, new-users, users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I am [continuing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) [honorary](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/and-the-best-new-user-of-2019-is) [post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/and-the-best-new-user-of-2020-is) based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2021 league the winner is:

## [Silly but True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true)

[image: Silly but True place in user league screen shot]

Coming in at #11 with 8,981 reputation in just 3 months is an excellent way to start contributing to the site. Please join me in congratulating this exceptional new user!

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria are:

| year | user | year rank | reputation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2020](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/and-the-best-new-user-of-2020-is) | [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez) | 12 | 9,252 |
| [2019](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/and-the-best-new-user-of-2019-is) | [Invisible Trihedron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115696/) | 19 | 8,239 |
| [2018](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) | [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/) | 9 | 14,253 |
| [2017](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) | [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/) | 6 | 26,201 |
| 2016 | [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/) | 18 | 15,596 |
| 2015 | [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/) | 4 | 35,709 |
| 2014* | [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/) | 7 | 14,897 |
| 2013 | [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/) | 10 | 6,998 |
| 2012 | [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/) | 4 | 26,834 |
| 2011 | [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/) | 1 | 21,720 |

*Honorary mention to [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) in 2014 as he came in first with 77,625 points, but joined and reached the leagues in December of 2013 therefore technically not qualifying for this contest.

Comment: I put some links in as the years, I think that's nice, but happy if you would rather leave it as just part of '...am continuing this honorary post based...'

Comment: Finally [getting my props](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment37882_11636) :-)

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Oh, I didn't even think to do it that way... I like it!

Comment: I wonder where I'd rank if we applied the same 'honourable mentions’ as Valorum? I joined Dec 2011, but I'd gotten ~30k rep by that time in 2012  how're you working these out?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Oh no, what can of worms have it opened! Now I remember why I wanted to keep things simple.

Comment: Mwahahahaha excellent. Going by https://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation, I had 43 site rep on 1st Jan 2012, and had earnt 32004 by 2012/12/31. But don't worry about adding it, like you said let's keep it simple.

Comment: That's silly, but true.