# And the Best New User of 2022 is

Tags: discussion, new-users, users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I am continuing this honorary post based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2022 league the winner is:

## [Andrew](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/149495/andrew)

[image: Andrew leaderboard ranking]

Finishing in #6 with 20,553 reputation is certainly impressive (fifth all time for new users). Please join me in congratulating this exceptional new user!

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria are:

| year | user | year rank | reputation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2021](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/and-the-best-new-user-of-2021-is) | [Silly But True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true) | 11 | 8,981 |
| [2020](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/and-the-best-new-user-of-2020-is) | [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez) | 12 | 9,252 |
| [2019](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/and-the-best-new-user-of-2019-is) | [Invisible Trihedron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115696/) | 19 | 8,239 |
| [2018](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) | [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/) | 9 | 14,253 |
| [2017](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) | [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/) | 6 | 26,201 |
| 2016 | [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/) | 18 | 15,596 |
| 2015 | [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/) | 4 | 35,709 |
| 2014 | [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/) | 7 | 14,897 |
| 2013 | [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/) | 10 | 6,998 |
| 2012 | [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/) | 4 | 26,834 |
| 2011 | [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/) | 1 | 21,720 |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you all! I hope to keep up the good work!

Answer (score 11):

Very well done. A worthy contribution!

[image]