# And the Best New User of 2023 is

Tags: discussion, users, new-users, contest

As a way to celebrate the New Year and lasting contributions to the site by new users I am continuing this honorary post based on a simple premise...

The user with the highest rank in the yearly reputation league that was not previously ranked. For the Year 2023 league the winner is:

## [alexg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/160834/alexg)

[image]

Finishing #14 with 4,154 reputation is a great way to start off on the site. Please join me in congratulating this exceptional new user!

---

Previous years winners based on the criteria are:

| year | user | year rank | reputation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2022](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13833/57310) | [Andrew](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/149495/andrew) | 6 | 20,533 |
| [2021](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/and-the-best-new-user-of-2021-is) | [Silly But True](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/145218/silly-but-true) | 11 | 8,981 |
| [2020](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/and-the-best-new-user-of-2020-is) | [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez) | 12 | 9,252 |
| [2019](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/and-the-best-new-user-of-2019-is) | [Invisible Trihedron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/115696/) | 19 | 8,239 |
| [2018](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/and-the-best-new-user-of-2018-is) | [Jenayah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98028/) | 9 | 14,253 |
| [2017](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/and-the-best-new-user-of-2017-is) | [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/) | 6 | 26,201 |
| 2016 | [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/) | 18 | 15,596 |
| 2015 | [Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/) | 4 | 35,709 |
| 2014 | [Royal Canadian Bandit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21600/) | 7 | 14,897 |
| 2013 | [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/) | 10 | 6,998 |
| 2012 | [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/) | 4 | 26,834 |
| 2011 | [Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/656/) | 1 | 21,720 |

Comment: Is it that time of year again, where I complain bitterly about being excluded from the list because I joined on 26th December 2013?

Comment: @Valorum And what a fine tradition it has become. Happy New Year!

Comment: @Valorum I think that time of year will be when spring is in the air. Surely you shouldn't have to complain about the list in the same month it comes out? Wait until everyone has forgotten about it and will be confused!

Comment: @Valorum Come on, there was 6 days before 2014. That's plenty of time to get 1.2k reps from the daily rep cap, and some bounties, which would total to at least 7k reps; basically what I got in 6 years. All right, I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 13):

Very well done. A fine contribution :-)

[image]